# How to create intermediate class in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I hav this models

```
from django.db import models
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField

# Create your models here.


class Video(models.Model):
    video_author = models.CharField(default='Bongo Media', max_length=20)
    video_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    video_file = models.FileField(blank=True)
    video_image = models.ImageField(default='image.png')
    video_embed_link = EmbedVideoField(blank=True)
    video_descriptions = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    video_pubdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_recommended = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.video_title


class Artist(models.Model):
    artist_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist_videos = models.ManyToManyField(Video)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist_name
```

In database i have a lot of videos and artists. in views.py how can i query so that when i click to the artist name i  can see only he is videos, or is there any mistake in my models? Or is the intermediate class  needed?, if so, how can i create the intermediate class and how to query data with intermediate class so that  i can filter all videos belonging to one artist

Answer (score 0):

Is `artist_songs` actually `artist_videos`?

```
videos = Artist.objects.get(artist_name="John").artist_videos
for video in videos:
    print(video.video_title)
```

Comment: I think this is somehow helpful

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this, but I think that in the above coding, the variable of "videos" is actually a title of the video file. Also, "artist_songs" is not introduced anywhere there.
So, to the answer of your question, no.

Comment: Now Its `artist_videos`  not artist_songs